# Identify ActiveMQ asyncrhonous message failures?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have ActiveMQ persistent queue and due to performance i'm publishing to producer using async mode.

```
 ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL);
 factory.setUseAsyncSend(true);
 PooledConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(factory);
 Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
 connection.start();
 Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
 MessageProduer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
 Queue queue = session.createQueue(qName);
 producer.send(queue, message);
```

Is there a way to register handler to get the error/success of `producer.send()` method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like jms 1.1 specification does not allow to register call back in send method and jms 2.0 allows it ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html ). Since ActiveMq based on jms 1.1 there's no standard way to register callback. However ActvieMQ `javax.jms.MessageProducer` implementation `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer` allows to register callback and I used that to create my solution ( but unfortunately i had to abandon `PooledConnectionFactory` because there was no way to get `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer` from  `PooledConnectionFactory` approach.

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL);
factory.setUseAsyncSend(true);
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MessageProduer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
Queue queue = session.createQueue(qName);
((ActiveMQMessageProducer)producer).send(queue, message, new AsyncCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onException(JMSException exception) {

        }
    };);
```